# Is is possible to create bxCAN communication between two devices with just CAN1?

Tags: stm32, can

I'm using two nucleo-l433rc-p boards, which only have the can1 peripheral. The only guides I find online use both CAN1 and CAN2 in their communication so I'm asking if it is even possible to do. If it is, how? (I'm also using an MCU2561 transceiver)

Comment: What is **bx**CAN communication?

Comment: You just need one CAN peripheral per MCU so why wouldn't it be possible? Multiple CAN peripherals are only used when you have multiple buses.

Comment: @Velvet It's the name of the CAN controller in STM32 microcontrollers. Iirc it comes in various flavours, where some are archaic.